# Does Morocco have a financial entry requirement?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, proof-provenance-of-funds, morocco

Most countries have a proof of funds or means of subsistence requirement but I cannot find any info whatsoever about Morocco other than "Visitors who do require a visa must provide pay slips and bank statements from the previous three months with their application."

Comment: What is your nationality, and what is the reason for your travel to Morocco? In my experience, tourists from visa-exempt nations who show up at Moroccan airports with a return ticket and hotel reservation are not subject to much scrutiny, but of course this is no guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://www.moroccanembassylondon.org.uk/en/viisa.html Morocco does not appear to have an overt subsistence requirement other than to provide:

- A return ticket with confirmed reservation;
- Travel Insurance;
- Bank statement;
- A hotel booking, or Introduction of a "Voucher";
- Or attestation of invitation duly legalized, in case of family visit, including guarantee of covering medical and possible repatriation expenses
- Or request from an authorized travel agency or recommendation of the Ministry of Tourism or the representation of the Moroccan National Tourist Office

In the absence of a defined amount, an adequate proof of funds level typically depends on the nature of the trip and the likely associated costs, plus proportionate affordability (for example, planning to spend your entire life savings on a two week holiday may well be a red flag leading to a refusal). Websites such as https://www.budgetyourtrip.com/morocco are a useful source to help understand what a reasonable budget should be.

The general principles described in [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) are also a good guide.